# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os
image_path ="D:/Ana/ana1111/random.jpg"
print (os.path.exists(image_path))
img=cv2.imread(image_path)
print(img)
print(img.shape)
windowname='image'
cv2.imshow|(windowname,img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is mycode of opencv for  image displaying.
I am getting this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'tuple'`

Answer (score 1):

Was that a typo or did you add an extra `|` after `cv2.imshow`?

Additionally, you may consult the docs for [cv2.imshow()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html) to see if your code is structured correctly.